# Delete second row in a cell in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In order to create some list, I've been copy some data from the web. 
Unfortunately it looks like it has been added second row for each record it need.

For example:

[image: sample image]

Each record is in the same line, and I'll need to have only the first line of each record (only "Alpena Community College" from the record "Alpena Community College
Alpena, MI"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a new line character in every cell and you want to extract everything before the new line, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(A2:A, "^(.+)\n")))
```

(where A is the column with the addresses and your data starts in row 2 --> change to suit).
After that, you can copy the output and use 'paste special' (values only) to overwrite to original column...